# System.OverflowException: 'Conversion overflows.' during reading Decimal from DB

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I've got fairly big value in DB: 888512650000.0.

I was able to store it in the database using `SqlBulkCopy` - no issues there.

But when I'm trying to read this value using `SqlCommand` -> `SqlDataReader`, I get an error:

> System.OverflowException: Conversion overflows

The exception is thrown even if I'm using simple:

```
var whatever = reader["ColName"];
```

The value can easily be parsed to decimal using eg. `decimal.Parse("888512650000.0")`, there's no overflow issue.

Column definition in the database:

```
 ColName Numeric(31, 17)
```

How can I read this value from DB using C#?

PS: I read other, similar questions, but there weren't replies that would answer my question.

Sample code that throws the exception:

```
using SqlConnection connection = new("connection_string");
await connection.OpenAsync();

using SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT ColName FROM Table"

using SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();

while (await reader.ReadAsync())
{
    var whatever = reader["ColName"]; //exception thrown here
}
```

Example problematic value:

```
888512650000.0
```

Full exception:

> System.OverflowException: Conversion overflows.   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Decimal()   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Value()   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_String()   at System.Data.DataReaderExtensions.GetString(DbDataReader reader, String name)   at Program.$(String[] args) in C:\Users\...\source\repos\Program.cs:line 30

I've already tried to retrieve this columns using
`GetDecimal()` and `GetString()` - each resulted in the same exception (call stack was a little bit different for each of calls, of course)

Comment: Please add whole your code and table and example Data

Comment: Added sample code, when it comes to DB, only mentioned column matters, all other columns are working just fine.

Comment: Post the actual *full* exception text returned by `Exception.ToString()`, not just the message. The full text, including the stack trace, probably shows what cast was attempted. You didn't try to read the value as a decimal anyway, you tried to read it as an object. Use [GetDecimal()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdatareader.getdecimal?view=net-7.0) to read a decimal value

Comment: SqlDataReader checks field type and for mentioned column it states that it's System.Decimal, so it's retrieving value as object is just because it's boxed by [] operator - actual type matches what was read from DB.

Comment: @PiotrWojsa you can to use cast "cast( [ColName] as nvarchar(100))" and parse in C# " var whatever = decimal.Parse( reader.GetString(0));"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After whole day of searching and reading, solution was really easy.
**AVOID** using `System.Data.SqlClient`, use `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` package instead. It's able to handle values mentioned in question.